# Is there any way to find whose wall I posted on using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Using the graph api,

graph.facebook.com/me/feed returns all my status updates and posts made by me.

Is there any way to get the wall posts made by me, for example, if I posted on John Doe and Jane Smith's walls, is there an api endpoint that would return those posts, or at least, return the names/ids of the people whose walls I posted on?